# Авторизация в приложении Android

Tags: php, java, android, sql, база-данных

Есть сайт, к нему разрабатывается приложение Android (на Java). База данных у них соответственно общая - MySQL. Необходимо реализовать авторизацию пользователя в приложении, то есть пользователь вводит свой email и пароль и после этого может просматривать данные профиля (например, ФИО и другие), а также отправлять определённые сообщения и при этом сервер должен понимать, что они пришли именно от этого пользователя. Не могу нормально сформулировать, поэтому не могу найти ничего внятного, хотя задача стандартная. На данный момент связь с сервером осуществляется с помощью POST-запросов с использованием библиотеки OkHttp, связь с БД уже есть и работает, можно зарегистрироваться и даже войти, но при этом данные о пользователе приложению не передаются, просто проверяется пара email/пароль на соответствие той, что уже есть в БД.

---

**Собственно вопрос:** как вообще реализуется авторизация, в какую сторону искать, как подгружать все эти данные с сервера? Как "удерживать" эти данные в приложении, нужно ли создавать локальную БД или может ещё как-то их хранить, чтобы постоянно не отправлять запросы удалённой БД?

Comment: Скорее всего также как и на сайтах. Генерировать токен для пользователя и хранить в базе. Только в роли клиента выступает приложение, вместо браузера. На Android у приложения хранить токен авторизации можно в той же БД или xml, да хоть в текстовике. Смотря как реализовано будет

Comment: Обычно это делается при помощи API, к которому вы сможете обращаться напрямую, минуя Web. API может быть SOAP, REST. gRPC - на ваш выбор. Проверьте если ваш сайт имеет его, и используйте.